# CCButton taking touch priority over CCNode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

So I have a `CCNode` called `menuNode` that has a few children including a `CCScrollView`. It is essentially a small menu that pops up when the user wants it to. To close out the `menuNode` I added a button to the scene that is the parent to this `CCNode`. This button is called `exitButton`. The button's preferred size takes up the users entire screen. The point of this design is that when the user touches outside of `menuNode`, `exitButton` removes itself along with `menuNode`. In other words, when the user taps outside of the menu, the button itself and the menu should close.

The problem I am having is that even when the user taps inside the menu, `exitButton` takes the touch and closes the menu. This should only happen when the user touches outside of the menu. My line of thinking was that if I add `exitButton` to the scene before I add `menuNode`, the `menuNode` should technically be on top of `exitButton` and therefore `exitButton` should not be taking the touch if the user taps inside the menu. However I just realized this is not true.

This is my code:

```
-(void)addPlant
    [self addChild:exitButton];
    [self addChild:menuNode];
}

-(void)removePlant
{
    [exitButton removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    [menuNode removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

What is the correct and most efficient way to design this feature?